# Force carbonating then bottling

Tags: bottling, carbonation, kegging, force-carbonation

I've run into a "bottled yesterday" situation and I need to have 2 12oz bottles for an event tomorrow. The beer in question is a NEIPA.

How would I calculate the PSI needed for a crank and shake if I want a target of 2.6 for my c02 volume @60-64 degrees? The charts I've seen don't really cover the duration needed. Brewer's friend gives me a psi of 26.8 but I don't know how I would calculate how much more I need to do it in less time.

Total time would be ~8-9 hours under pressure until bottling and then ~1 hour to chill.

### Update:

I started carbonating last night at ~27-28psi so I'll be getting ~18 hours of carbonation.

I'm still curious if there is a method to calculate this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's isn't any formula or table established for a timescale of force carbonating.

*The unknown variables that vary too much to quantify are liquid density, container shape, liquid volume, cO2 delivery method and location.*

The formulas for cO2 volumes based on pressure and temp are well documented, but lack the duration needed.

More pressure does reduce the time but it can easily be over shot.

Personally I either do a top down carbonation at serving pressure of 12psi and takes about 5 days in a 5g corney in an average 5% beer shish FG of 1.010-1.016.

Or if I want to rush it I attach to the out line for a bottom up carb at 12PSI (or desired psi for volumes) and then swirl the keg by slightly tipping it on a bottom edge, grabing it by a handle and get the beer to swirl. This takes about 20-30 minutes. You know when it's done be cause you can hear your regulator releasing gas and co2 bubbles in the tank, when it stops taking gas it's done.